# What is the best way to compare enum and non-enum objects in Java?

Tags: java

Having the following definitions

```
public interface AnInt {
    int value();
}

public enum FirstTwo implements AnInt {
    ONE(() -> 1),
    TWO(() -> 2);
}
```

Is there a way to correctly implement comparison to use standard equals:

```
class AnotherOne implements AnInt {
    @Override
    int value() {
        return 1;
    }
}
ONE.equals(new AnotherOne()); // -> true
```

Comment: Your enum doesn't compile but I guess the implication is that it would have a ctor that would take an `IntSupplier` and use it to power the `value()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the `equals()` of `java.lang.Enum` (the parent of all `enum` classes) is final, you can't do this.

And in general, considering objects of different classes, especially if there is no parent-child relation between those classes, equal is an accident waiting to happen (unless carefully designed). I recommend solving this in a different way (e.g. a custom comparison method, or wrapper classes that provide a facade for the equality check, a `Comparator<AnInt>` implementation as companion to the `AnInt` interface, etc).

Comment: I added, and then removed a suggestion to implement `Comparable<AnInt>`, as `Enum<E>` already implements `Comparable<E>` and `compareTo` is also final.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!
My thoughts was in the same direction. Ultimately I've decided to replace enum with pure class implementation and specify static constants within the interface for required instances .